# OpenPGP and 3 Yubikeys, Best Practice for Encryption Subkey

Tags: openpgp, yubikey

New to OpenPGP. I have 3 Yubikeys, one for my laptop, one for my desktop, and one which I plan to keep in cold storage as a backup. My plan was to create a S/E/A subkey for each Yubikey, attached to my primary key (9 subkeys total). But, now I learned that a message encrypted with one E subkey can not be decrypted by another key, so this may not be the best approach. I was thinking I could load the same encryption (E) subkey on each Yubikey, but I would not have protection if a Yubikey is lost or stolen. I am curious, what is the best way of doing this?